# How to convert dataframe to spark rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am looking to get a Spark Row(s) from Apache Dataframe. I have tried searching online but could not find anything

Comment: Given a DataFrame `df`, `df.rdd.collect()` would produce an `Array[Row]` - but that's usually a very bad idea (collects the data into the driver application's memory). Why do you need a `Row`? What do you plan to do with it?

Comment: row.getAs[Any]("fieldName")

Answer (score 1):

You can do

Dataframe.map(x => x.getAsROW)